# Nginx domain config to handle both wildcard and main domain

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm having hard time with my nginx. All I'm trying to do is having SSL certifications both on *.example.com and example.com  points. Certicates just for wildcard config work without any problem but when I try both at the same time nginx ignores either of the config. Let me clarify it. Here is the config for *.example.com which works fine:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name .example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5500;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0003/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0003/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

But when I add `example.com` to this file it gets ignored:

```
.
.
.
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name .example.com example.com;
    location / {
.
.
.
```

nginx test:

```
root@localhost:/etc/nginx/sites-available# sudo nginx -t
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

I even tried putting it in a different server block or even in a different config file but every time one of my settings gets ignored.

one more tip. Sometimes browsers map https://example.com to https://www.example.com which helps. But This doesn't happen all the time and in some cases, the user sits at https://example.com, where the browser throws an SSL error.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Besides the fact your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, you might want to specify which Nginx version...

Comment: here it is: nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Comment: `.example.com` is a wildcard name that already includes `example.com`. Hence the duplication warning. Also, use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files and ensure that there are no other `server` blocks that could affect your question.

Comment: I see. if .example.com already covers `https://example.com`, why do browsers throw SSL certification error on that path while `https://www.example.com` works like a charm? and here is the SSL error I get for `https://example.com`: NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID by the way I'm OK to share my domain name which has the issue if it helps